# How do I go about calculating the enthalpy of a solution with an unknown salt?

Tags: enthalpy, salt

I have the $\Delta T$, I have the specific heat of the calorimeter, I have known weights/mass. I know the salt is lithium-based. What steps do I take to calculate the enthalpy of the solution so I can compare my answer to the specific molar enthalpies of possible lithium salts?

If the equation I use is $Q = m \times c \times \Delta T$, what mass do I use and do I use the specific heat of the calorimeter?

I just don't understand this. I've been hitting my head off the problem with research and trying to attack it from different directions and I'm just stuck.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/1105/102629

Comment: You determine Q from your equation using the mass and specific heat capacity of the calorimeter (you ignore the heat capacity of the salt, as it's small relative to that of the calorimeter).   Then you divide Q by the number of moles of salt you added to get the enthalpy of solution.  If you want further details, most general chemistry textbooks should have worked calorimetry examples.